# JavaScript if fails with [""] (an array containing an empty string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript compare arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532062/javascript-compare-arrays)

```
​var x = [""]
if (x === [""]) { alert(​​"True!") }​​ 
else { alert("False!") }
```

For some reason, this alerts `False`. I cannot seem to figure out why. What can I do to make this alert `True`?

Comment: Two objects are equal only if they refer to the same object. Even `[] != []`. One simple way to compare them would be to compare their JSON representations.

Comment: Why should it alert true? You compare two different objects. The happen to have the identical values, but they are still two distinct objects.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @Blender those are arrays, not objects, but your statements still hold for arrays.

Comment: @jbabey: Arrays are objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compare values not whole arrays

...as they're objects and you're working with implicit references here. One object is stored in your `x` valiable which you're trying to compare (by reference) with an in-place created object (array with an empty string element). These are two objects each having it's own reference hence **not equal**.

I've changed your example to do what you're after while also providing the possibility to have an arbitrary number of empty strings in an array:

```
if (x.length && x.join && x.join("") === "")
{
    alert(​​"True!")
}​
else
{
    alert("False!")
}
```

This will return *True!* for any arrays like:

```
var x = [];
var x = [""];
var x = [null];
var x = [undefined];
var x = ["", null, undefined];
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Two objects are equal if they refer to the exact same Object. In your example x is one Object and [""] is another. You cant compare Objects this way. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be reliably compared this way unless they reference the same object. Do this instead:

```
if ( x[0] == "" )
```

or if you want it to be an array:

```
if ( x.length && x[0] == "" )
```

Comment: `instanceof Array` is not reliable when you're dealing with cross-document objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use toString in this case. Careful, there are some outliers where this will not work.

```
var x = [""]
alert(x.toString() == [""].toString()) // true
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is a vastly safer option that could be used in the same way.

Comment: `[","].toString() === ["",""].toString(); // true`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, two objects are equal only if they refer to the same object. Even `[] == []` is `false`.

A probably slow but generic solution would be to compare the string representations of the two objects:

```
JSON.stringify(a1) == JSON.stringify(a2)
```

Comment: It's much simpler to join the two arrays and check whether values are the same than iterating over all elements.